# Invalid Static Cast

Tags: c++

I have taken code from here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template

However it treats uint8_t and int8_t as ASCII and so I want to cast anything that is to int16_t.  I tried to do this:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void log(const char *s, T value1, Args... args)
{
while (*s) {
    if (*s == '%') {
        if (*(s + 1) == '%') {
            ++s;
        }
        else {

        if ( std::is_same<T, uint8_t>::value || std::is_same<T, int8_t>::value )
        {
            int16_t x = value1;
            int16_t x = static_cast<int16_t>(value1);
            std::cout << x;
        }
        else
        {
           std::cout << value1;
        }

            log(s + 1, args...); // call even when *s == 0 to detect extra arguments
            return;
        }
    }
    std::cout << *s++;
}
throw std::logic_error("extra arguments provided to printf");
}
```

However I got the error:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  
std::allocator<char> >’ to type ‘int16_t’
```

Is there anyway not to print out ASCII?

Comment: The problem I see is that `x` is declared twice.

Comment: Those are the two ways I tried to cast.  Just playing around.  The error is as described.  It will not compile.

Comment: Well the code you have in your question will compile fine for me if name the second `x` as `x1`.

Comment: OK, strange.  I am using GCC 4.4.6

Comment: How about posting the code that actually has the problem you describe?

Comment: OK, I will add some more details.  Taking away that cast will make it compile.

Comment: You could always just use `printf("%d",value1);` and the thing would not be misinterpreted as ASCII.

Comment: I am not allowed to use printf in my code I must use cout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem:

Like your compiler said:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,  
std::allocator<char> >’ to type ‘int16_t’
```

I suppose your calling your log function like this:

```
log("my % thing %....", /*my std::string*/ stringToto, 5,/*....*/);
```

And there is the problem!

When the compiler see you want to `static_cast` a `std::string` to a `int16_t`  it generate an error!

## What you've done wrong

This part:

```
    if ( std::is_same<T, uint8_t>::value || std::is_same<T, int8_t>::value )
    {
        int16_t x = value1;
        int16_t x = static_cast<int16_t>(value1);
        std::cout << x;
    }
    else
    {
       std::cout << value1;
    }
```

Why? In fact, even if your condition (`std::is_same<T, uint8_t>::value || std::is_same<T, int8_t>::value`) is false, your compiler will interpret your `static_cast`

## What should you do

Use a function that get an argument (whatever is its type) and generate an std::string, like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::string
my_to_string(T) { return ("what is this type?"); }

template<>
std::string
my_to_string(std::string s) { return (s); }

template<>
std::string
my_to_string(int integer) { return (std::to_string(integer)); }
```

and then call it in your log function like this:
std::cout << my_to_string(value1);

## Good Luck improving your work!

Comment: Yes, some of my values are strings.  I forgot about those.  Thanks.  I will do this.

Answer (score 3):

If-statements don't make compile-time decisions; the compiler will always check both branches.

You need to create an overloaded `write()` function, where the default version streams to cout, and which you can overload for specific types (such as `char`).

Comment: Or hope that the optimizer will eliminate one of the branches ... not the most reliable way to write code though.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker No, that doesn't help if one of the branches has invalid code in a specific instantiation. If it's just about worrying that the dead branch is in the resulting code, relying on the optimizer is perfectly fine.

Comment: Afaik, that depends on the compiler (which is one of the reasons I said it's not very reliable) - I don't think the C++ standard mandates that dead code needs to be  anything more than syntactically correct (vs. semantically correct). But then, you're probably right that in practice most compilers would enforce both due to the way they build up the parse tree.

Comment: I have never heard of a compiler that skips semantic validation of dead branches, and the tendency currently is to be more aggressive in validation rather than less. Besides, the standard totally does mandate that dead code be semantically correct - more specifically, it mandates that all code be semantically correct, having no concept of dead code at all.

Comment: For my statement, I was basing myself on the "as-if" rule. Specifically : "an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects affecting the observable behavior of the program are produced." Anyway, this is mostly a theoretical argument, and I didn't intend to go off on a tangent like this. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to call your function with a `std::string`, which cannot be converted to `int16_t`. Instead of the `static_cast`, you could use the following function template which is overloaded for strings:

```
template<typename T>
auto cast_to_int(T const& t) -> int16_t
{
    return static_cast<int16_t>(t);
}

auto cast_to_int(std::string const& t) -> int16_t
{
     std::istringstream ss(Text);
     int16_t result;
     ss >> result;
     return result;
}
```

Eventually, you have to overload it for further types.

Call the above via

```
std::cout<< cast_to_int(value1);
```

instead of the whole block

```
    if ( std::is_same<T, uint8_t>::value || std::is_same<T, int8_t>::value )
    {
        int16_t x = value1;
        int16_t x = static_cast<int16_t>(value1);
        std::cout << x;
    }
    else
    {
       std::cout << value1;
    }
```